# Can't restore gnome-panel after replacing it with Avant-Window-Navigator

Tags: 11.04, gnome-panel, panel, ubuntu-tweak

I just replaced **gnome-panel** with **Avant-Window-Navigator**, but was unhappy with the result. I tried to restore gnome-panel by using **Ubuntu Tweak**, and **Configuration Editor**. But neither of them would recognize the value `gnome-panel`. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Open a terminal, and run `gksudo
  nautilus /usr/bin/`
- Find the file named **gnome-panel**,
  right-click on it, and select
  **Properties**.
- Click on the Permissions tab, and
  tick the option that says: **Allow
  executing file as program.**

[image]

- Close the **Properties** window, and execute the file.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to reset gnome-panel configuration with :

```
gconftool-2 --recursive-unset /apps/panel
```

and then

```
sudo reboot
```

or

```
pkill gnome-panel
```

to relaunch them automatically

Comment: I actually used Ubuntu Tweak's nifty restore feature to do just that. That alone didn't do anything though, see my answer below.